# Connection failed with psql and pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

I use postgres 11, I just try to connect with one of my user to psql and pgadmin4

my pg_hba.conf file

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                 peer
host    sito        lcm_admin       127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    sito        sito_lcm        127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

My postgres user have a password.

I tried my posgres user, sito_lcm and lcm_admin to connect to pgAdmin4, alway get

```
Invalid username or password
```

I know there are good because It's the one I use to connect to posgres db in a java program

for psql i tried

> su - postgres
> typed my password

authentication fail

tried with one of my db user

```
psql -U lcm_admin sito
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "lcm_admin"
```

Edit

With Daniel Vérité tips, I can connect to psql but not to pgAdmin4

[image]

First time i see this screen, my last connection was a few month ago, don't know if some updated had created this issue

Comment: Do you have a Linux user `lcm_admin` and are you logged in to Linux with that user?

Comment: no theses user only exist for the db

Comment: Then you can't use `peer` authentication - that only works if your DB users match your Linux users

Comment: psql --host=localhost --dbname=sido --username=lcm_admin  don't work too and should use md5 authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this rule in pg_hba.conf

```
host    sito        lcm_admin       127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

You probably want to invoke psql that way:

```
psql -U lcm_admin -h 127.0.0.1 sito
```

Then it will ask for a password instead of failing with  "Peer authentication failed".

Note that rules in pg_hba.conf are tested in their order in the file (top to bottom), and it stops at the first one that matches.

---

About connectiong with pgAdmin4:

As mentioned in https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/getting_started.html there is an additional step to access pgAdmin4 itself, as an application.

In a server deployment, an email address and password are asked at installation time. If you don't remember the password but you gave a valid email address, the link "Forgotten your password" might work for you.
Otherwise I guess reinstalling pgAdmin4 from scratch might work too.

Personally, I launch pgAdmin4 as a docker container without a persistent volume:

```
$ docker run -p8080:80  -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=foo@example.com -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=bar dpage/pgadmin4
```

Then I connect to http://localhost:8080 and the email/password to enter on the first page are those environment variables passed on the command line.

Comment: I can connect now with psql, but not with pgAdmin4

Comment: anything special to do de be able to connect to my local postgres server?